# C++ partial template function specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a primary template function:

```
template <typename T, int U>
void print() { 
    std::cout << "int is " << U << std::endl;
}
```

How to make a partial specialization for function *print*, so that U is inferred based on a type of T?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
void print<T, 1>(); // If T is float

template <typename T>
void print<T, 2>(); // If T is Eigen::half

print<float>();
// Prints "int is 1"

print<Eigen::half>();
// Prints "int is 2"
```

Comment: Function templates can't have partial specialization.

Comment: Can you modify the base function?  If so, it may be easier to remove the `U` parameter and figure it out using some sort of type trait.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I can modify the base function. Will the type trail happen in compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't partially-specialize functions, and specializations are selected *after* all of the template's arguments are known, so you can't do this with partial specialization.

What you can do is have a *separate* function template that has a single argument that simply calls through to the underlying function template:

```
template <typename T>
void print();

template <>
void print<float>() {
    print<float, 1>();
}

template <>
void print<Eigen::half>() {
    print<Eigen::half, 2>();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae63a2861f6fb121)

This will do what you want, but it would still be possible to override the behavior by explicitly calling `print<float, 42>()`.  If you don't want that to be possible, you can remove the second parameter from the base function and use a type trait to determine it:

```
template <typename T>
struct IntDeterminer;

template <>
struct IntDeterminer<float> : std::integral_constant<int, 1>
{};

template <>
struct IntDeterminer<Eigen::half> : std::integral_constant<int, 2>
{};

template <typename T>
void print() {
    std::cout << "int is " << IntDeterminer<T>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d2bb1f45adc92c3)

Comment: Both your and @463035818_is_not_a_number answers are correct and produce the required result. Nevertheless, I've decided to to choose the 463035818_is_not_a_number answer, and that's why: 1) For demo 1, it's an additional extra call to "internal" function with 2 parameters, that happens in run time. 2) For demo 2, the value retrieval... Here is a question: Does it happen in compile time or in run time? It's a const, so probably in compile time? Correct? If so, the 2nd demo aligns with my expectations as well.

Comment: @Andrey your notion of runtime vs compile-time is a little off. In the first version here indeed there are two function calls rather than one, but the compiler has all it needs to inline the calls and I doubt that there is any notable effect of the additional function call.